# Django model delete: instance vs queryset delete

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to know the best way to delete a model instance.

*Instance delete* example:

```
myModel = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
myModel.delete()
```

*Queryset delete* example:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).delete()
```

What are differences between *instance* vs *queryset* delete techniques?
Are there any side effects in using the *queryset* instead of the *instance* delete and vice-versa?

P.S. If you think your answer is version specific, assume I'm asking for Django >= `1.6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance delete involves two queries: One for selecting the object. Other for deleting the object.

While Queryset delete involves only one query: deleting.

Side effect of instance delete: `myModel.pk` (== `myModel.id` normally) become `None` after the delete.

Comment: Does it have any implications on "cascading" deletes on "child" tables; i.e. rows in other tables related to model being deleted?

Comment: @JosvicZammit, Yes it does. According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-delete): When Django deletes an object, by default it emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE – in other words, any objects which had foreign keys pointing at the object to be deleted will be deleted along with it.

Comment: @JosvicZammit, You can customize it using `on_delete` field attribute. See [`ForeignKey.on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

Comment: Thanks, +1ed, will not mark the question as correct yet so that if anyone comes up with any other differences we'll get that answer in too. Thanks!